# partition error

Tags: partitioning, 12.10

while doing create partition following error shows up

```
error creating partition: helper exited with exit code 1: In part_add_partition: device_file=/dev/sda, start=307198163968, size=118189196288, type=0x83
Entering MS-DOS parser (offset=0, size=640135028736)
MSDOS_MAGIC found
looking at part 0 (offset 32256, size 307197725184, type 0x07)
new part entry
looking at part 1 (offset 307198163968, size 332936512512, type 0x0f)
Entering MS-DOS extended parser (offset=307198163968, size=332936512512)
readfrom = 307198163968
MSDOS_MAGIC found
readfrom = 586446013440
MSDOS_MAGIC found
readfrom = 307205982720
No MSDOS_MAGIC found
Exiting MS-DOS extended parser
looking at part 2 (offset 0, size 0, type 0x00)
new part entry
looking at part 3 (offset 0, size 0, type 0x00)
new part entry
Exiting MS-DOS parser
MSDOS partition table detected
containing partition table scheme = 1
got it
Error: Invalid partition table on /dev/sda -- wrong signature 0.
ped_disk_new() failed
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a partition on a removable drive? A hard drive? During the Ubuntu installer? Most importantly, *is the disk bigger than 2TB?*

Comment: i have just delete my drive and want it as an ntfs so when i try to partition it show the above error

Comment: I understand that, but is the drive bigger than 2 TB, and is it an external drive?

Comment: no, neither it is 2TB nor external drive

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you run fdisk on the partition. I've done it before and had success with similar errors.

> If you also encounter any of the above problem, simple run fdisk by sudo fdisk /dev/sda >press p and then press w. You'll see a message "The partition table has been altered!".

Taken from suggestion here:
http://techspalace.blogspot.com/2011/10/solved-invalid-partition-table-on.html

**NOTE: This will erase your partition table**

Answer (score 0):

Please refer Link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8BkXgVx7mE for detailed steps to partitioning

Comment: Please share the essential part of the solution since there is no guarantee that the link works in future